# Re-implementation of library functions

Tags: c, linux, system

I have this function for running a child process with error checking. But I need this code for a different operating system (xv6) which doesn't have support for `fcntl` and `getrlimit`. How should I reimplement them ? or is there any other way?

```
pid_t run_child(char *progname, char *argv[], int child_stdin, int child_stdout, int child_stderr)
{ pid_t child;
  struct rlimit lim;
  int max;

  if((child=fork()))
  { 
    return child;
  }

  if(child_stdout==STDIN_FILENO)
  { 
    child_stdout=dup(child_stdout);
    RC_CHECK(child_stdout>=0);
  }

  while(child_stderr==STDIN_FILENO || child_stderr==STDOUT_FILENO)
  { 
    child_stderr=dup(child_stderr);
    RC_CHECK(child_stderr>=0);
  }

  child_stdin=dup2(child_stdin,STDIN_FILENO);  
  RC_CHECK(child_stdin==STDIN_FILENO);
  child_stdout=dup2(child_stdout,STDOUT_FILENO);  
  RC_CHECK(child_stdout==STDOUT_FILENO);
  child_stderr=dup2(child_stderr,STDERR_FILENO);  
  RC_CHECK(child_stderr==STDERR_FILENO);

  RC_CHECK(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,&lim)>=0); 
  max=(int)lim.rlim_cur;

  for(int fd=STDERR_FILENO+1; fd<max; fd++)
  { int code=fcntl(fd,F_GETFD);

    if(!code&FD_CLOEXEC) 
    { if(fcntl(fd,F_SETFD,code|FD_CLOEXEC)<0)
        perror("run_child"); /* Report errors, but proceed */
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would say the answer depends on what is the "different operating system."

Comment: The "different operating system" is xv6.

Comment: Look at the documentation for xv6 to see if the system API provides any functions that do similar things.   If it does, use them to emulate the function.   If it doesn't, simply remove affected sections of code from your function.

Comment: It doesn't,The part which has the unsupported functions asks the kernel to close all other open files when we exec,  so should I remove them in that case ?

Comment: Just close whatever files you have opened (other than standard streams)